# mongoskin dynamic collection name error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I need to insert into a Mongodb collection where the collection name is inside a variable.
but it seems its not possible or my code is wrong.

```
db.collection(colname).insert(dbjson, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result) console.log('Added!');
});
```

but it throw this error:

```
Error: collection name must be a String
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at checkCollectionName
```

any idea on how could i deal with this error?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
db.collection(colname.toString()).insert(dbjson, function(err, result)
```